htaccess / mod_rewrite URL redirection with Apache RewriteRule: How do I hide the folder path in the browser?
I have a problem with rewriting mod_rewrite. I have an Apache on Windows Server.
Documentroot: D:/web
Inside /web there are some folders and subfolders.
For example D:/web/subfolder1/subfolder1_1/
I would like the user to access the path subfolder1/subfolder1_1/ via (test) localhost/hello
when entering. But localhost/hello WITHOUT the user ever seeing the folder path as a URL in the browser.
With this rule:
RewriteEngine On
# Internal redirection
RewriteRule ^mirowiki(/.*)?$ /subfolder1/subfolder1_1$1 [PT,L]

the redirection works, but the browser does not display
localhost/hello, after calling it display the real path localhost/subfolder1/subfolder1_1
However, I would like localhost/hello/xy.html .php etc. to appear so that the user cannot recognize the structure behind it.
What am I doing wrong?
I thought the Flag: PT [PT] (Pass Through): Forwards the request internally without changing the URL in the user's browser or?
